# using two xpathselectors on the same page

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have a spider where the scraped items are 3: brand, model and price from the same page.

Brands and models are using the same sel.xpath, later extracted and differentiated by .re in loop. However, price item is using different xpath. How can I use or combine two XPathSelectors in the spider?

Examples:

for brand and model:

```
titles = sel.xpath('//table[@border="0"]//td[@class="compact"]')
```

for prices:

```
prices = sel.xpath('//table[@border="0"]//td[@class="cl-price-cont"]//span[4]')
```

Tested and exported individually by xpath. My problem is the combining these 2 to construct the proper loop.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Provided you can differentiate all 3 kind of items (brand, model, price) later, you can try using XPath union (`|`) to bundle both XPath queries into one selector :

```
//table[@border="0"]//td[@class="compact"] 
    | 
//table[@border="0"]//td[@class="cl-price-cont"]//span[4]
```

**UPDATE :**

Responding your comment, above meant to be single XPath string. I'm not using python, but I think it should be about like this :

```
sel.xpath('//table[@border="0"]//td[@class="compact"] | //table[@border="0"]//td[@class="cl-price-cont"]//span[4]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As a beginner I never seen this before. Could you please tell me should this be a 2 strings separated by `(|)` or just one string?

Comment: Thanks. Just tried your method. Price xpath now returns some additional elements like commas and prices aren't matched with models and brands. 
I'll ask new question with updated spider and link to the website.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are having trouble associating the price with the make/model because both xpaths give you a list of all numbers, correct? Instead, what you want to do is build an xpath that will get you each row of the table. Then, in your loop, you can do further xpath queries to pull out the make/model/price.

```
rows = sel.xpath('//table[@border="0"]/tr')  # Get all the rows
for row in rows:
    make_model = row.xpath('//td[@class="compact"]/text()').extract()
    # set make and model here using your regex. something like:
    (make,model) = re("^(.+?)\s(.+?)$", make_model).groups()

    price = row.xpath('//td[@class="cl-price-cont"]//span[4]/text()').extract()

    # do something with the make/model/price.
```

This way, you know that in each iteration of the loop, the make/model/price you're getting all go together.